# Anemone - NoMethodError: undefined method `xpath' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, anemone

I'm just starting to learn more about writing a web crawler in Ruby which is designed to crawl my blog and find broken external links using the Anemone gem and the rake task below...

```
task :testing_this => :environment do
    require 'anemone'
    rooter = 'myblog.com'
    banned = ['tel:','@', '#', 'facebook.com', 'twitter.com', 'pinterest.com', 'linkedin.com', 'youtube.com','reddit.com', 'wikipedia.org']
    extensions = %w( .jpg .jpeg .png .doc .pdf .js .css .xml .csv. .exe .zip .gzip )
    start = Time.now
    Anemone.crawl("http://#{rooter}/", {:threads => 4, :discard_page_bodies => false, :obey_robots_txt => false, :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}) do |anemone|
        begin
            anemone.on_every_page do |page|
                puts page.url.path
        links = page.doc.xpath("//a/@href")
        if (links != nil)
          links.each do |link|
            this_link = link.to_s
            unless extensions.any? { |exten| this_link && this_link.include?(exten) }
                unless banned.any? { |word| this_link && this_link.include?(word) }
                    unless this_link.include? rooter
                        # puts this_link
                        obl = URI.parse(URI.encode(this_link.strip)).host
                        unless obl.blank?
                            if obl.include? 'www.'
                                obl = obl.gsub("www.", "")
                            end
                            Obl.find_or_create_by(url: obl)
                        end
                    end
                  end
                end
          end
        end
        end
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => ex
    puts ex
    end 
    end
    time_t = Time.now - start
    puts "-------------"
    puts "#{time_t} seconds"
    puts "-------------"
end
```

It's working on my demo folder, however, I've been using https://arthurdejong.org/webcheck/demo/ to test it and I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `xpath' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried building an array of extensions as I did wonder if that was what was causing the issue but so far no luck.

Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this or work the problem through?

Comment: I would suggest refactoring this code first, since is it very hard to read and debug. Once it is done chances are that the bug will be spotted by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Artur - As I said, I'm pretty new to Ruby and web crawlers so now I've got it running it's time to refactor the code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error comes from `page.doc.xpath` : `page.doc` is nil.

Try to `inspect` your `page` in the `on_every_page` method.

You also can add a `if` before `.xpath` to avoid error:

```
anemone.on_every_page do |page|
  puts page.url.path
  if page.doc.present?
    links = page.doc.xpath("//a/@href")
```

Comment: Adding in the .present? fixed the problem and avoided the error.